# Display a Variable from a Method in a File in the /lib/ directory on a View in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a file called `foo.rb` in my `/lib/` directory it reads:

```
module Foo
  def some_method
    @text_1 = "Hello!"
  end
end
```

How can I get the results of this method to show up in a View?

I've seen that I need to include the following line in the `/config/application.rb` file:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib
```

However, I do not completely understand how to pass a variable from a module in a file saved in the `/lib/` directory - to show up in a View. I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.I agree with 
Beerlington.

You can do it in an other way,
It is not mandatory to add **config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib** to application file.Because by default the files which are located in /lib directory won't be executed at first when we run an application using **rails s**.
In order to make those files to be loaded,we need to include that line in application.rb.
Otherwise,we can directly write it as below,

**In model,**

require 'Filename'

class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base

```
 include Foo
```

end

**In controller,**

require 'foobar'

class BuyerController < ApplicationController

```
include Foobar
```

end

**In foobar.rb,**

module Foobar

def Foobar.foobar

```
   "Hello world!"
```

end

end

**In view,**

<%= Foobar.foobar %> (You can directly call the method by using **Modulenmae.Methodname**)

Answer (score 2):

In order to get that value to show up in the view, you'll need to understand how modules are used in Ruby. Typically modules are mixed into other classes either by including or extending them. This would then make that method available to another class which could then be referenced in the view. In your case you might want to include it so it becomes available to instances of whatever class you put it in. Say you have an ActiveRecord model called MyClass and you include Foo. You can then call `my_method` on instances of that model as demonstrated below:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Foo
end
```

In your controller:

```
class MyController
  def new
    @my_class = MyClass.new
  end
end
```

In your view:

```
@my_class.some_method
```

Having said all that, it seems like there might be a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do :)